# error installing older version of driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom

The new broadcom wifi module wl is buggy, so I read somewhere that installing an older version of bcmwl (bcmwf-kernel-source 6.30.223.141) fixes the problem. I downloaded the deb from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1). Then installed it using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and it shows

```
 (Reading database ... 158905 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1) over (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.8.0-36-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.8.0-36-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
```

and output of

> /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log

is [here](http://pastebin.com/D0N8jRE4).
**Kernel version** - 4.8.0-36-generic 
**wifi driver** - Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01) 
**OS** - Kubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Answer (score 1):

The older version of `wl` will not build for the `4.8` kernel.

You can look into `/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log` to see what is the problem.

If you look into the [new version](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb), you will see that there are some patches that add support of new kernels.

You can backport these patches and rebuild the package.

Comment: I have posted the output of /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log . Is there any way it can be built?

Comment: You need to change the source.

Comment: What all changes should be made? make.log shows errors about missing arguments.

Comment: That means that the 4.8 kernel has less arguments.